# How can i use KLIPS (Kotlin Language Integrated Production System) for an Android App?

Tags: android, kotlin, clips

https://github.com/vjache/klips - (inspired by C Language Integrated Production System = CLIPS)

I tried to include this library to gradle like this:

```
implementation "org.klips:klips:1.0"
```

But it doens't work.
Anyone know if it's possible to solve this and use the klips in android?

Comment: can you post what the error ?

Comment: This is said to me when i try to sync the project : Failed to resolve: org.klips:klips:1.0

Comment: how do you find that this library have this gradle? `implementation "org.klips:klips:1.0"` I didnt found on their github? perhaps this library didn't have gradle supported

Comment: In the link on github I put in the question I found it. It said it's for Android apps, and I figure out that I can import like this (I take  "org.klips:klips:1.0" from pom.xml).

Comment: repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }  
  implementation "com.github.vjache:klips:oc-android-library-v0.0.6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say in the comment that the library found release on the [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/#vjache/klips/v0.0.6)

you can use this gradle in your build gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.vjache:klips:v0.0.6'
}
```

and

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
}
```